# Can't Add Platonic Solids in Blender via Script

Tags: scripting

After watching the following tutorial, I thought I was going to customize it a bit and add a dodecahedron in the place of the ico sphere.

Tutorial that I followed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-cgCXg7Z3o

As mentioned in the tutorial, I found out via the console, that to add a dodecahedron, Blender runs the following command:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add(source='12')
```

So below was my best guess at implementing it and it doesn't work. Any idea how I'd go about doing this?

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from math import sin, cos, radians

primitive_add = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add

# get cursor loc - Script Modified by SardiPax
cursor = context.scene.cursor_location

radialdist = 2.0

xsize = 0.15
ysize = 0.15
zsize = 0.15

theta = 0.0
pi_over_8 = 6.28 / 16.0

levels = -10
maxlevels = 10
divi = 2.0
inci = 0.25

while levels < maxlevels:

    while theta < 6.28:
           x = cursor.x + (radialdist-(levels+ 2*cos (theta+levels/divi))) * cos (theta-levels/divi)
           y = cursor.x + (radialdist-(levels+ 2*sin (theta-levels/divi))) * sin (theta-levels/divi)
           z = cursor.z+levels
           bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add(source='12',location=(x, y, z))

           bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(xsize* cos (theta-levels/divi), ysize* cos (theta-levels/divi),  zsize* cos (theta-levels/divi)), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, snap=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', snap_point=(0, 0, 0), snap_align=False, snap_normal=(0, 0, 0), texture_space=False, release_confirm=False)
           theta += pi_over_8

    theta = 0.0
    levels += inci

radialdist = 1.0
```

Also at: https://gist.github.com/robksawyer/93597658ccc75fba324e

I'm using the following addon:
https://github.com/jaredly/blender-addons/blob/master/add_mesh_solid.py

Comment: `primitive_solid_add()`  has no location argument , instead you can add `bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(x, y,  z))`

Answer (score 2):

first you have to add the add mesh: Extra Objects...

[image: extra objects]

also, first try with

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add(source='12')
```

best